# How can I get ssh working on Mint Olivia?

Tags: linux-mint, openssh

I have a Mint KDE VM (under VMware Fusion on Mavericks), and it is refusing ssh connections. I have not enabled UFW, and openssh-server installed without reported error. However, when I attempt to open a ssh connection from the Mint VM or the Mavericks host, the connection is refused. From Mint:

```
christos@christos-virtual-machine:~ > ssh localhost
Read from socket failed: Connection reset by peer
```

From Mavericks:

```
Inner Sanctum ~/mirror $ ssh christos@mint
Connection closed by 172.16.144.182
```

What can I do so sshd is listening and not impaired on Mint Olivia?

--EDIT--

```
christos-virtual-machine christos # service sshd status
sshd: unrecognized service
[1]christos-virtual-machine christos # service iptables status
iptables: unrecognized service
[1]christos-virtual-machine christos # nmap localhost

Starting Nmap 6.00 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2013-12-13 15:40 CST
Nmap scan report for localhost (127.0.0.1)
Host is up (0.0000040s latency).
Not shown: 996 closed ports
PORT    STATE SERVICE
22/tcp  open  ssh
139/tcp open  netbios-ssn
445/tcp open  microsoft-ds
631/tcp open  ipp

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.05 seconds
```

Comment: What is the result of `service sshd status` and `service iptables status`

Comment: `nmap localhost` from the Mint VM would help also.

Comment: Thanks Jonathan, odd that the serivces aren't recognized. Are you using `/etc/init.d/xxxx restart` to bounce your services?  My next question is did you update your `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` to use more than just 127.0.0.1 for the IP address. I know some distros will have that set by default to keep you from shooting yourself in the foot.

Comment: I set /etc/ssh/sshd_config to listen on 0.0.0.0, and restarted. Still not listening: "Connection closed by UNKNOWN"

Comment: Try going through this tutorial: http://community.linuxmint.com/tutorial/view/814. 2 areas to scrutinize are the firewall and also make sure that sshd is configured to accept connections.